# Custom route with List

Tags: react-admin

Wondering how to use the List component from a custom route. Looks as though I'm supplying the correct props

I have a custom route of

```
<Route path="/facilities/:facilityId/audits" render={(props) => 
            <Audits
                {...props}
                hasCreate={false}
                hasEdit={false}
                hasList={true}
                hasShow={false}
                resource={props.location.pathname.substring(1)}
                options={{label: "a label"}}
                basePath={props.location.pathname}
                permissions="organisation"
            />
     } />
```

My list component is

```
export const Audits = (props) => 
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" sortable={false} />
            <TextField source="date" sortable={false} />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>;
```

However I'm getting the error of:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (ListController.js:432)

...

The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Connect(translate(UnconnectedListController))
    in Unknown (created by List)

Props in the Audits component as below:
[image]